# "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused" at node.vm.provision time, but successful when executed from a vagrant ssh

Tags: bash, kubernetes, vagrant

I'm doing a *Kubernetes* deployment into a VM, using https://github.com/techiescamp/vagrant-kubeadm-kubernetes/blob/main/Vagrantfile model.

At the end of its `node` part, just after the

```yaml
node.vm.provision "shell", path: "scripts/node.sh"
```

I've added a

```yaml
node.vm.provision "shell", path: "ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-create.sh"
```

where `ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-create.sh` has this content:

```bash
echo "Création du déploiement Kubernetes pour ecoemploi"
kubectl apply -f ecoemploi-namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f ecoemploi-postgis-configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f ecoemploi-postgis-pv-pvclaim.yaml

kubectl apply -f ecoemploi-postgis-sgbd.yaml
kubectl apply -f ecoemploi-postgis-service.yaml
```

At `vagrant up` time, it fails with this message:

```
node01: Création du déploiement Kubernetes pour ecoemploi
node01: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
node01: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
node01: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
node01: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
node01: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

But if I enter by `vagrant ssh node01` and type this, it works:

```bash
vagrant@worker-node01:~$ kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-namespace.yaml
namespace/ecoemploi created
vagrant@worker-node01:~$ kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-configmap.yaml 
configmap/postgres-config created
vagrant@worker-node01:~$ kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-
ecoemploi-postgis-configmap.yaml   ecoemploi-postgis-pv-pvclaim.yaml  ecoemploi-postgis-service.yaml     ecoemploi-postgis-sgbd.yaml        
vagrant@worker-node01:~$ kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-pv-pvclaim.yaml 
persistentvolume/postgres-pv-volume created
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-pv-claim created
vagrant@worker-node01:~$ kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-service.yaml 
service/postgres created
vagrant@worker-node01:~$ kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-sgbd.yaml 
deployment.apps/postgres created

kubectl get all -n ecoemploi
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/postgres-5698988bf-npw9j   1/1     Running   0          27s

NAME               TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/postgres   NodePort   172.17.52.216   <none>        5432:32187/TCP   40s

NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/postgres   1/1     1            1           27s

NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/postgres-5698988bf   1         1         1       27s
```

So, I changed my script with:

```bash
echo "Création du déploiement Kubernetes pour ecoemploi"
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-pv-pvclaim.yaml

kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-sgbd.yaml
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-service.yaml
```

or

```bash
kubectl apply -f ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-configmap.yaml
[...]
```

but it still failing the same way.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

```bash
echo "Création du déploiement Kubernetes pour ecoemploi"
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-pv-pvclaim.yaml

kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-sgbd.yaml
kubectl apply -f /vagrant/ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-postgis-service.yaml
```

is the good way to write my script.
But, it must be executed as a normal `vagrant` user, to ensure *Kubernetes* starts its normal way, first.

```yaml
node.vm.provision "shell", path: "ecoemploi_scripts/ecoemploi-create.sh", privileged: false
```